# How to integrate SMOTE resampling and feature selection into RFECV

Tags: python, python-3.x, classification

I am working on a dataset of shape (41188, 58) to make a binary classifier. The data is highly imbalanced. Initially, I intend to do feature selection by *RFECV* and this is the code I am using which has been borrowed from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py):

```
# Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")

# The "accuracy" scoring is proportional to the number of correct classifications
min_features_to_select = 1  # Minimum number of features to consider
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(5),
              scoring='accuracy',
              min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select)
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(min_features_to_select, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) +
                  min_features_to_select), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

I got the following result:
[image]

then I changed the code to `cv=StratifiedKFold(2)` and `min_features_to_select = 20` and this time I got:

[image]

In none of the cases above, resampling was done. Since resampling should be applied to the training data, and here I am using cross validation therefore, each training data fold should be resampled (e.g. SMOTE) as well. I wonder how to integrate resampling and feature selection into RFECV?